# Python dataframe to SQL using pyodbc not INSERTing row.name correctly

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, insert, pyodbc

I'm using `pyodbc` to take a python dataframe and INSERT into an MSSQL table. This normally works well for me, but I'm having issues on one of the columns not populating correctly (`df.name` to be specific). Here is the portion of code that contains the SQL code to insert the dataframe:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (StartDate, Name, AcctNbr) values(?,?,?)", 
                        row.startdate, row.name, row.acct)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The dataframe looks like this if I run df.head(3):

```
df[['startdate','name','acct']].head(3)
Out[18]: 
    startdate              name        acct
0  2023-08-01         Doe, John     6711380
1  2023-08-01         Doe, Jane     4711680
2  2023-08-01       Smith, Jack     8708379
```

When I run the python code to insert into SQL, the table then populates like this in SQL.

| StartDate | Name | AcctNbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | 0 | 6711380 |
| 2023-08-01 | 3 | 4711680 |
| 2023-08-01 | 6 | 8708379 |

I can't figure out why the SQL INSERT statement isn't giving the correct names in the "Name: column. Is `row.name` reserved as something else in python?

Comment: `row` is a pandas `Series` object which has its own `name` attribute. Try using `row["name"]` or `row.get("name")` instead of `row.name`